# HTML JS CSS: No puedo modificar la posición Y del elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero hacer que un elemento con un display flex en un header suba usando `transform: translate()`, pero no funciona.

Lo primero que hago es usar `.innerHTML` en mi código JS para que inserte esto:

```js
barTitle.innerHTML += "<span id='doctorName'>‎ " + user.name + " <br><span id='xpDisplayer' style='font-size: 25px;'>(0/100)</span>" + "</span>";
```

Aclaro que `barTitle` representa este div:

```html
    <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <!-- Aqui es donde esta barTitle, y lleva una imagen al principio de todo -->
                    <h1> <a id="bar-title" style='margin-left: 20px; text-decoration: none;'><img id='range' src='images/ranges/range-1.png'></a></h1>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-abajo2"></i></a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header><br><br><br>
```

Donde señalé `barTitle` es donde se inserta lo del JS. Mi problema es que este span: `<br><span id='xpDisplayer' style='font-size: 25px;'>(0/100)</span>" + "</span>"` quiero que suba, entonces añado este código CSS:

```css
    #xpDisplayer {
        transform: translate(20px, 0);
    }
```

El resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué; sin embargo, si lo muevo horizontalmente, sí funciona. ¿Qué hago?

Edit: Adjunto todo el codigo: https://pastebin.com/QHYr61Wy

Comment: Puedes usar la herramienta o `snippet` para mostrar un [mcve], al ser HTML, CSS y JavaScript lenguajes soportados en [es.so] para ello.

Comment: Agrega el resto del codigo que teniendo solo una parte es dificil saber que es lo que esta mal. El resto del codigo html css y javascript asi te pueden ayudar mejor.

Comment: `transform: translate(x,y);` espera dos parámetros, el primero es X, el segundo es Y. Si no te funciona así, prueba utilizando a `transform: translateY();`

Comment: @MauricioContreras Eso estaba por hacer, pero mi pagina utiliza localStorage y no sabia como hacer para ilustrarlo, y ademas tambien requiere una imagen y no se si se puede colocar

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego Lo añado si quieres, pero ten en cuenta que se utilizan imagenes y el localStorage

Comment: @ElFuturoLlego Ya esta, añadi un pastebin

Comment: @EvilFearzZ Lo probe y sigue sin funcionar :(

Comment: Ya esta solucionado :D

Comment: que era? estaba intentando arreglarlo, tu código es medio confuso jaja, no se porque usas un H1 para envolver una imagen 2 textos y no se que mas xdd cual era el problema?

Answer (score 1):

> **Solucion**

Lo que hice fue añadirle al span `display: block;` y después fui posicionándolo donde yo queria usando `transform: translate(115px, -52px);` de esta forma:

```
#xpDisplayer {
    display: block;
    transform: translate(115px, -52px);
}
```